# Comparing a parameter against null values

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, where-clause

I'm new to SQL and I want to know the approach to solve this small problem

```
Select * from ApplicationData where ApplicationId = @AppID
```

AppID can be null as well as it could contain some value. When null value is received, it return all the application. Is there any way we can alter Where clause.

Example

```
Select * from ApplicationData where  Case When <some condition> then
ApplicationId = @AppID else ApplicationId is null;
```

Thanks

Comment: What is issue if you return all records when you recieve null?

Comment: From where I see it, it seems to be a bad idea to have that field null as it looks like the key of the table. That said, you beter handle that kind of stuff in you bunsiness layer than in queries, but that's only my opinion...

Comment: I only need the data with contain null values.

Comment: so when you get null in @AppID then you want to return row with null values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT * FROM ApplicationData
WHERE (ApplicationId IS NULL AND @AppID IS NULL) OR ApplicationId = @AppID
```

This is an alternate approach:

```
SELECT * FROM ApplicationData 
WHERE ISNULL(ApplicationId, -1) = ISNULL(@AppID, -1)
```

Comment: That's a cool idea, but it does the checking twice all the time. I guess using `CASE WHEN` is slightly more efficient.

Comment: What about the case when an index is defined on ApplicationId? Will be the index used when @AppId has a not NULL value?

Comment: @MihaiBejenariu: the index will be used but most likely it will be a full scan instead of lookup.

Comment: Is there a way to write this query so the index to be taken into account?

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing this in a stored procedure then use logic to switch between the two filter requirements. However this will only give you optimal code if the ApplicationId column is included, preferably as the first key, in an index.

```
IF @AppID IS NULL
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM ApplicationData
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM ApplicationData WHERE ApplicationId = @AppID
END
```

Why is this the best solution? Because the SQL engine will create two query plans for this stored procedure. The query plans will give you the optimal solution for the two filtering requirements. As they are small statements and you only require two possible outcomes you're not creating any burden on the query cache and your code is very readable. If your requirements were more complex, with many variation of filtering then you should consider Dynamic SQL.

If you are not using stored procedures then your application layer should dynamically create the two separate query strings.

There has been many articles written on this subject. I could dig out a few good ones for you if you need.

Comment: Interesting solution. What about the case you have 5 NULLable fields with 5 variables?

Comment: This is arguably the best approach, a good article on the topic is [Dynamic Search Conditions in T‑SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html), which goes over pros and cons and alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM ApplicationData
WHERE CASE WHEN @AppID IS NULL THEN ApplicationId IS NULL
           ELSE ApplicationId = @AppID END;
```

Alternatively, you can split it into two conditions like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ApplicationData
WHERE ApplicationId = @AppID
   OR (ApplicationId IS NULL AND @AppID IS NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE @AppID IS NULL OR ApplicationId = @AppID;
```

Comment: What about the case when an index is defined on ApplicationId?

Comment: @MihaiBejenariu and what's the problem?

Comment: Will be that index used with your condition?

Comment: The first part **@AppID IS NULL** is true so all records will be included (full scan anyway)

Comment: And when @AppId has a concrete value, will index be used?

Comment: the same way when usual parameter is used

Comment: The idea is the index is not used and the question is if you could rewrite the query so the index to be taken into account.

Answer (score 0):

always check your parameter first before put into consideration, remember, the bracket is very important, especially for multiple parameters

--Example For Single parameter

```
Select * from ApplicationData where (@AppID IS NULL OR ApplicationId = @AppID)
```

--Example for multiple parameter(s)

```
Select * from ApplicationData 
where (@AppID IS NULL OR ApplicationId = @AppID)
OR (@AnotherAppID IS NULL OR AnotherApplicationId = @AnotherAppID )
```

make sure that u have covered your parameter(s), then your query will work fine, cheer =)

Answer (score 0):

For your case you should do like this

```
IF @AppID IS NULL
BEGIN
   SELECT * FROM ApplicationData WHERE ApplicationId is null
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   SELECT * FROM ApplicationData WHERE ApplicationId = @AppID
END
```